# Spring - Junit of a web application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, junit

Ive built some junit service-layer testing on a spring container web application.

Regularly my web application runs on a tomcat server.

My question is: When i run the project as a junit test does a tomcat instance is starting somehow? or does junit knows how to run the tests without a real tomcat against it?

Thanks,

Comment: A unit test typically tests a single class. You don't need a Tomcat server to invoke methods on a class. And JUnit won't magically start a Tomcat server: it has 0 knowledge of Tomcat, doesn't come with a bundled tomcat instance, doesn't know how to start a tomcat server and deploy a webapp. How comes you're writing JUnit tests without knowing what this test actually does? What's the code of your unit test?

Comment: I'm not a tester, I'm a developer , the tests were written by our qa engineer which is fairly new to java, Junit and spring (his a .net engineer originally)

Comment: Ouch. Developing unit tests is the developer's job. It's not the job of a tester.

Comment: Its a service layer testing, not a unit testing, Junit is the tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This very much depends on the type of tests you're talking about. Unit tests which test the functionality of a specific class in isolation will not require Tomcat to run. These simply execute the logic in these classes providing mocked dependencies as required. You're using Spring so I assume you're using DI to provide dependencies.

You also have integration tests. These might be simple integration tests e.g. DAO tests which run against a database fixture or functional tests which run against an application running in a container. The latter type will require that you have a running application.

Edit:

> Its a service layer testing, not a unit testing, Junit is the tool

If this is correct it sounds like the test falls into the simple integration test category which requires a database but no application container. Therefore your JUnit tests need to setup this database (could be in memory e.g. H2) and populate it with a known start position. JUnit will then execute your tests against this fixture and tear it down when done.